# How to access Skill Api (standardized-data)?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am doing R&D on LinkedIn apis and i want to access following api.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/standardized-data/skills#get_all

By registering with App, its throwing an error that your don't have permission. Is this all paid API? do i need to enroll any other program? I required more information the same.

Please help.

Thanks